# Selenium and BeautifulSoup - Trying to scrape content from page 1 THEN go to page 2 and so on

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, chrome-web-driver

I am having a hard time understanding how to grab all of the pages content that I want. I am able to grab the information I want from page 1 but getting the next 15 pages is the challenge.

I am using selenium and chrome webdriver to get the info from this site.

[This is what I have so far, this is an example of grabbing the 1st piece of info I need from the 1st page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j96Nx.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed, the URLs of the pages on that website follows a particular pattern with `;page=X` appended at the end of the URL to load the content of a specific page, where X is the page number you want.

For example `https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/automotive/tires-wheels/tires.html?adlocation=LOL_TiresSCLP_MegaNavAuto_19309_en;page=15` loads the contents of page 15.

In your code, you can loop through each page and scrape the content.